# how to save an uploaded image in react-native

Tags: react-native

native-image-picker code to upload the image,What the problem when uploading the image it uploads and show the selected image, but when i want to save the image in database, It saves like  [object Object] in data base. When i want to to Get the data the image is not showing.

- Here i am attaching my my code:

  ```
  var {
      StyleSheet,
      View,
      Image,
      Text,
      TouchableOpacity,
      AlertIOS,
      TextInput,
      ScrollView,
      NativeModules: {
          UIImagePickerManager
      }
  } = React;

  class Profile extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
              avatarSource: this.props.data.data.profilepic,
          };
      }
      avatarTapped() {
          var options = {
              title: 'Select Photo',
              cancelButtonTitle: 'Cancel',
              takePhotoButtonTitle: 'Take Photo',
              chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: 'Choose From Library',
              allowsEditing: true,
              returnBase64Image: false,
              returnIsVertical: false,
              quality: 0.8,
              noData: true,
              storageOptions: {
                  skipBackup: true
              }
          }

          UIImagePickerManager.showImagePicker(options, (didCancel, response) => {
              console.log('Response = ', response);

              if (didCancel) {
                  console.log('User cancelled image picker');
              } else {
                  if (response.customButton) {
                      console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
                  } else {
                      // You can display the image using either:
                      //var source = {uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data, isStatic: true};
                      // var source = response.uri ;
                      var source = {
                          uri: response.uri.replace('file://', ''),
                          isStatic: true
                      };
                      console.log("source:" + source);  // in console it shows[object Object]
                      this.setState({
                          avatarSource: source
                      });
                  }
              }
          });
      }
      render() {
          return ( < View style = {
                  styles.right
              } >
              < View style = {
                  styles.column
              } >
              < TouchableOpacity onPress = {
                  this.avatarTapped.bind(this)
              } >
              < View > {
                  this.state.avatarSource == "" ? < Image style = {
                      styles.image
                  }
                  source = {
                      {
                          uri: uri,
                          static: true
                      }
                  }
                  /> : < Image style = {
                      styles.image
                  }
                  source = {
                      this.state.avatarSource
                  }
                  />
              } < /View> < Text style = {
                  styles.changeText
              } > Change < /Text> < /TouchableOpacity> < /View> < /View>
          )
      }
  }
  ```

when I try to save the image in database it saves like [object Object].can any one give me suggestions how to resolve it.Any help much appreciated

Comment: Could oh show the actual code that is uploading the image? What language are you using for your backend?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I mean object object
I want to post a Comment but I am short a couple of points. [object object] means it is a object object. There are different types of objects in javascript. try `JSON.parse(source)`